# Too many sapplys to cleaning a dataframe in R

Tags: r

How can I improve this code?

```
  data$tidy <- sapply(data$tidy,function(x) {x <- gsub("one","1",x)})
  data$tidy <- sapply(data$tidy,function(x) {x <- gsub("two","2",x)})
  data$tidy <- sapply(data$tidy,function(x) {x <- gsub(“first”,"1",x)})
  data$tidy <- sapply(data$tidyfunction(x) {x <- gsub("second","2",x)})
```

The general idea is: if I find a "one" or "first" I replace that for 1.

This code is working, but I am completely sure that perhaps could be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have no idea what your `data$tidy` looks like, I'll make up some fake data.

```r
mydata <- data.frame(tidy = c("my one is not two", "two going into first or second", "twenty five or six to four"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mydata
#                             tidy
# 1              my one is not two
# 2 two going into first or second
# 3     twenty five or six to four
mydata$tidy <- gsub("(one|first)", "1", gsub("(two|second)", "2", mydata$tidy))
mydata
#                         tidy
# 1              my 1 is not 2
# 2        2 going into 1 or 2
# 3 twenty five or six to four
```

Since you're doing substring replacement, neither `merge` nor `fuzzyjoin::` will do what you need. And while we can reduce/combine some of the patterns, I don't know an easy way around individual specification like that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I really appreciate the advice about "will do what you need"

Answer (score 3):

`gsub` is vectorized so you don't really need `sapply` here.

You could use `str_replace_all` here passing a named vector as `replacement` and `pattern`.

Using @r2evans data.

```
a <- c('1', '2')
names(a) <- c('one|first', 'two|second')
stringr::str_replace_all(mydata$tidy, a)
#[1] "my 1 is not 2"        "2 going into 1 or 2"   "twenty five or six to four"
```

Comment: So far, one of the biggest (only significant? for me) things `stringr` has over base R regex functions. Nice! (Doing this in base R dynamically would likely require `Reduce` and some trickery.)